# SQL Server update table with loop columns

Tags: sql-server, loops

I want update a few interdependent tables that each have 100 columns. A simplified version of what I'm trying to do is:

```
Update a
Set a.[2] = b.[1]*c.[mult]
from table1 a join table2 b on a.[id] = b.[id]
              join table3 c on a.[id] = c.[id]

Update b
Set b.[2] = a.[2]*d.[mult]
from table2 b join table1 b on a.[id] = a.[id]
              join table4 d on b.[id] = d.[id]
```

And then loop it for column 3, 4, 5, ..., 100 for table a and table b. I'm new to dynamic SQL and reading a few existing posts on similar topic doesn't solve my question, especially in this case table1 and table2 depend on each other.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is this the sort of thing that can be solved with a CURSOR? http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Comment: You don't need a cursor to update columns within a row. You don't need any looping here, you just need to buckle down and start typing a lengthy update statement. If you have all these columns that are dependent on the values of other columns you should look into computed columns instead of whatever it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: @DanForbes I want to know if CURSOR is the tool to be used in situations like this, where I'm trying to loop through column 2 to 100 for updating two tables that depend on each other, or if I should use some other approach. Thanks!

Comment: Cursors are used to loop through rows, not columns.

Comment: @Scott So is there something that can be used to loop columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple columns to update, you can do them all at once with the same update statement.  You have to list each one.

```
Update a
Set a.[2] = b.[1]*c.[mult],
    a.[3] = b.[2]*c.[mult],
    a.[4] = b.[3]*c.[mult],
    a.[5] = b.[4]*c.[mult],
    // etc.
    a.[100] = b.[99]*c.[mult]
from table1 a join table2 b on a.[id] = b.[id]
              join table3 c on a.[id] = c.[id]

Update b
Set b.[2] = a.[2]*d.[mult],
    b.[3] = a.[3]*d.[mult],
    b.[4] = a.[4]*d.[mult],
    b.[5] = a.[5]*d.[mult],
    // etc.
    b.[100] = a.[100]*d.[mult]
from table2 b join table1 b on a.[id] = a.[id]
              join table4 d on b.[id] = d.[id]
```

However, if you're trying to number your columns and access them by index, then your table structure is poorly designed.  Perhaps your tables should have a row for each index value and ID.  This allows you to select or join by ID and index.  For example,

```
Create Table table1
(
    [id]    int,
    [index] int,
    [value] int,
    Primary Key ([id], [index])
)

Create Table table2
(
    [id]    int,
    [index] int,
    [value] int,
    Primary Key ([id], [index])
)
```

Then you can join them like this:

```
Update a
Set a.[value] = b.[value]*c.[mult]
from table1 a join table2 b on a.[id] = b.[id] and a.[index] = b.[index]
              join table3 c on a.[id] = c.[id]
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply. The problem with updating multiple columns in 1 update statement is that a.[3] depends on b.[2], and b.[2] depends on a.[1], so I'll have to update a.[2] then b.[2] then a.[3] then b.[3], etc., in that order. That's why I wonder if there is a loop or recursive function I can use in here.